# HTML Text area with custom user font size style and colour

Tags: html, text, area

How can I create a text area in html where the user can change font style, size and colour. I have spent about an hour searching to no avail. I can find simple text boxes where users can input data, but not where they can change font size style and colour

thanks

Comment: You can use style for textarea.

Comment: I mean where the user, when they are using the html webpage, are able to change the font size style and colour whilst they fill in the text area, like a simple text editor for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very most basic, you might need to write some javascript.

You could possibly have a dropdown that shows font size from 4px to 30px, for example. Example:

```
<textarea id="textarea1">test 123</textarea>
<select onchange="textarea1.style.fontSize = this.value;">
     <option value="12px" selected="selected">12px</option>
     <option value="4px">4px</option>
     <option value="30px">30px</option>
</select>
```

For changing background color, the onchange code would be `textarea1.style.backgroundColor = this.value;` with possibly values `#ff0000` for red, `#00ff00` for green and so on.

For changing style, you might need a few if statements such as:

```
if(this.value == 'u')
    textarea.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
else
    textarea.style.textDecoration = '';
if(this.value == 'i')
    textarea.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
else
    textarea.style.fontStyle = 'normal';
if(this.value == 'b')
    textarea.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
else
    textarea.style.fontWeight = '';
```

Though you might need to customize the code above a bit to cater for combined styles such as bold italic.

Comment: this is perfect thank you, I'll do the same thing to  change colour and font thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try using TinyMCE text editor with custom configured toolbars (you should turn off toolbar buttons that you dont need)

Answer (score 2):

I think you looking for textarea (WYSIWYG) editors. You can find more by googling.  Try these,

**[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)**

Demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo

**[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)**

Demo: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

**For More**, Check these links for more editors,

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/14-jquery-and-non-jquery-rich-text-editors/

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
  #container {width:100%; text-align:center;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<textarea name="mytextarea" cols="10" rows="10" style="font-family:comic sans ms"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just like this, but in the text area, where the user has a selection of font sizes colours and fonts availible to choose from when entering text.

Comment: sorry i can`t get your question,can u explain  me.

Comment: Basically a text box area, but when you insert text into the text area, there are some drop down boxes that allow you to change the font style, font size and font colour of the text, whilst you are typing in the text box. Just like a very simple version of word, but in html/css

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
$('btn1').click(function(){
$('textarea').css("font-style","italic");
}
```

i think you have to create a list of buttons for each style and then change the second parameter of the css method as you want .